# Parquet file format performance issue with map reduce

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, parquet, orc

I have a 2.1TB uncompressed data which I am loading into 2 tables, both snappy compressed, but one with parquet file format and another is using ORC file format. While creating parquet file format, I am keeping hdfs block size same as parquet.block.size.

I am observing that my map reduce queries are performing very poor with parquet compared to ORC by a large margin. These are aggregate queries and ORC takes time under a minute, whereas the parquet is taking more than 5-6 mins. When I use Tez execution engine, then the performance is comparable.

I am using hdp 2.5.x version of distribution.

anyone faced similiar issue and any hints on improving the performance with MR alone?

Comment: This may depend on many factors in your files. Can you post the schema of these files and which query engine you use?

Comment: Just being curious... Why do you focus on MapReduce? Don't you get better performance with TEZ??